# Compiling local mof file in all the remote systems

Tags: c#, wmi

I have one mof file which will create custom class in the wmi repository. I am able to compile this file in the local system by using mofcomp.exe. but what i want is compile this mof file in all the remote machines(not manually compiling the file in each of the system). how can i do this.